# ajax request firing twice on button click

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, sweetalert2

I am using knockout and .net and have below html

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-bind="click: CalculateAge">Calculate</a>
```

Then in my typescript module i am calling function `CalculateAge` like below

```
CalculateAge= (data: any, event: Event) => {
        $('body').on('click', '#MyButton', () => { validateAge(); });
        let inputHtml = "<input type = 'text' style= 'width: 300px' id = 'inputHtml' value = '" + receiverEmail + "'></input>";
        let myButton =
            "<button id='myButton'>Calc</button>";

        let alert: any = {
            title: 'Please calculate',
            html: "<table>" +
                "<tr>" +
                "<td><label>Age</label></td> " +
                "<td style= 'padding-right: 5px'>" + inputHtml + "</td><td>" + myButton + "</td>" +
                "</tr>" +
                "</table>",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            showConfirmButton: false,
            cancelButtonText: "Cancel"

        };
        swal(alert);

        let options_warning: any = {
            title: 'Error',
            type: "warning",
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "ReEnter",
        };
        let options_success: any = {
            title: "Sent",
            type: "success",
            confirmButtonText: "Ok",
        }
        let options: any;

        function validateAge() {

            var age = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('inputHtml')).value;

            if (!age || age == "") {
                options_warning.title = "Age please fill";
                options = options_warning;
            }
            else {
                options = options_success;
            }

            swal(options).then(() => {
                if (options.type == "warning") {
                    swal(alert);
                }
                else {
                    $.post('MyApi/MyController/CalcualteAge',
                        { "Age": age }
                    );
                }
            });
        }           

    };
```

I click on href which opens sweet alert popup and i enter age and click on button called **myButton**. This checks if age is filled or not and then makes ajax call to calculate age. I dont care if webapi has failed or not.

When i click on **myButton** then everything goes ok and it makes ajax call only once.

But when i click on href to open popup and click on **myButton** then it throws error **Cannot read property 'value' of null**

and error is on line

```
var age = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('inputHtml')).value;
```

and it makes ajax call twice. I think something wrong with binding of **myButton**

Anyone idea how to resolve it?

Comment: Try moving the validateAge function outside of the calculateAge function. I believe it is getting immediately invoked, then it is getting called again on the `$('body').onclick` function

Comment: @Robert if i just move function ValidateAge outside CalculateAge then it is throwing syntax errors

Comment: you'll need to move your `options_warning`, `options_success`, and `options` variable declarations into the validateAge function as well. Also the function declaration you have: `function validateAge() { .... }` will need to change to `validateAge() { .... }` That should resolve your syntax errors. I'll put it in an answer so you can see the code. Hopefully that fixes the double ajax calls

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, try moving `validateAge()` outside of the `CalculateAge()` function like so:

```
CalculateAge = ( data: any, event: Event ) => {
    $( 'body' ).on( 'click', '#MyButton', () => { this.validateAge(); } );
    const inputHtml = '<input type = \'text\' style= \'width: 300px\' id = \'ReceiverEmailInput\' value = \'' + receiverEmail + '\'></input>';
    const myButton =
      '<button id=\'myButton\'>Calc</button>';

    const alert: any = {
      title: 'Please calculate',
      html: '<table>' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<td><label>Age</label></td> ' +
        '<td style= \'padding-right: 5px\'>' + inputHtml + '</td><td>' + myButton + '</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '</table>',
      type: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      showConfirmButton: false,
      cancelButtonText: 'Cancel'

    };
    swal( alert );

  }

  validateAge() {

    const options_warning: any = {
      title: 'Error',
      type: 'warning',
      confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
      confirmButtonText: 'ReEnter',
    };
    const options_success: any = {
      title: 'Sent',
      type: 'success',
      confirmButtonText: 'Ok',
    };
    let options: any;

    var age = ( <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById( 'inputHtml' ) ).value;

    if ( !age || age == '' ) {
      options_warning.title = 'Age please fill';
      options = options_warning;
    } else {
      options = options_success;
    }

    swal( options ).then( () => {
      if ( options.type == 'warning' ) {
        swal( alert );
      } else {
        $.post( 'MyApi/MyController/CalcualteAge',
          { 'Age': age }
        );
      }
    } );
  }
```

When a `validateAge` function is contained inside the `CalculateAge`, it is being treated as an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE). When IIFEs are assigned to variables, the function runs immediately when the `CalculateAge` function is invoked, in order to store the return value. `validateAge()` is then being invoked a second time when you add the click listener to `#MyButton`

Comment: there is no alert option inside validateAge function, so it will fail

Comment: it will fail on line swal(alert) in validateAge

Comment: I would pass in alert as a parameter to validateAge

Comment: where will be body on click event will be?